# What binaries are required to deploy LocalDb?

Tags: deployment, localdb

Many articles state that LocalDb is easy to install and some state that SQL Express is not needed to deploy an application that uses LocalDb.  However, I have found no reference that tells what binaries should be included in an install for an application that uses LocalDb.

Do I simply need to add the contents of "\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDb\Binn" to the application folder?

Is there a reference on this?

Answer (score 1):

You should still use LocalDB MSI to install it. It is just that LocalDB MSI is very simple, has no prerequisites on supported platforms, installs fast and asks you no questions.

Also, if your application uses ClickOnce installation, and you are using Visual Studio 2012, you can just mark LocalDB as chained dependency in your Deployment Wizard.

Otherwise you need to make sure your installer installs LocalDB MSI.

Comment: where do I find the LocalDB msi though?